# What is a Healthy Word™?

Tags: pattern, word-property

If a word conforms to a special rule, I call it a Healthy Word™.

Use the following examples below to find the rule.

| HEALTHY WORD™ | UNHEALTHY WORD™ |
| --- | --- |
| DIABETOLOGY | DIETOLOGY |
| GASTRONOMES | CHEFS |
| HYDROBIOLOGY | BIOLOGY |
| GLAMOURED* | GLOOMED |
| ASTRONOMIC* | ASTROLOGIC |
| MACAROONS | MARSHMALLOWS |
| AERODYNAMICS* | AERONAUTICS |
| MONARCHIST | REPUBLICIST |
| GENEROUS | BENEVOLENT |
| LABYRINTHODONT | LABYRINTH |
| GRAMOPHONE | RADIO |

*These words are Extra Healthy™.

And, if you want to analyze, here is a CSV version:

```
HEALTHY WORD™, UNHEALTHY WORD™
DIABETOLOGY, DIETOLOGY
GASTRONOMES, CHEFS
HYDROBIOLOGY, BIOLOGY
GLAMOURED*, GLOOMED
ASTRONOMIC*, ASTROLOGIC
MACAROONS, MARSHMALLOWS
AERODYNAMICS*, AERONAUTICS
MONARCHIST, REPUBLICIST
GENEROUS, BENEVOLENT
LABYRINTHODONT, LABYRINTH
GRAMOPHONE, RADIO
```

Comment: Now I don't have to feel guilty about eating macaroons all day - they're healthy!

Comment: If it is on the internet, it must be true, right? :D I also love them, so I made them healthy. :P

Comment: `AERONAUTICS` contains the word `ROSE`. Seems pretty healthy to me.

Comment: @CodeNewbie, I actually included only a few red colours that seemed more reddish to me. But maybe it was wrong of me doing so.

Comment: @CodeNewbie, I guess I need to broaden my own definition of "red".

Comment: @Mithrandir Pasta *is* healthy. ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

OK, let's give this a go. A Healthy Word™ is a word which

> contains all the letters of the word for a colour of red.

This fits because

> `DIABETOLOGY` contains BLOOD, `GASTRONOMES` contains MAROON, `HYDROBIOLOGY` contains BLOOD, `MACAROONS` contains MAROON, `MONARCHIST` contains CRIMSON, `GENEROUS` contains ROSE, `LABYRINTHODONT` contains BLOOD, and `GRAMOPHONE` contains MAROON.

And the Extra Healthy Words™:

> `GLAMOURED` contains RED and ROUGE, `ASTRONOMIC` contains MAROON and CRIMSON, and `AERODYNAMICS` contains RED and ROSE and CARMINE.

(Hat-tip to @MOehm for helping me to find a few of these.)

Comment: If you're counting GOLD then GLOOMED (unhealthy) also contains that.

Comment: Monarchist and gramophone also contain crimson. Aerodynamics contain carmine. I haven't found ruby, vermilion, cinnabar. Aerodynamic contains anaemic, which is decidedly not red.

Comment: @MOehm Gramophone doesn't contain crimson. Thanks for the rest though - adding them in! (I was disappointed not to see ruby or scarlet anywhere.)

Comment: It was supposed to be a red herring. (Sorry, I had blundered when copying from my notes.) As compensation, have this: Glamoured contains rouge.

Comment: For good measure, gramophone also contains maroon.

Comment: @MOehm Damn, how did I keep missing all these maroons and crimsons when I'd already found those words elsewhere? Thanks!

Comment: It seems Generous is an Extra Healthy one that I missed and Aerodynamics is even Extra Healthier than you think.

Comment: @Maria Which is the other red word in Generous? (Also, out of curiosity, why the name Healthy?)

Comment: @randal'thor The same is also in Glamoured. About Healthy - I was kinda hoping someone would figure it out, but it is generally considered that someone who is reddish in colour (skin, tongue, etc) is healthy (as opposed to white/pale - which is considered sick. - although I did not include anagrams of white/pale in the unhealthy ones).

Comment: Generous contains Rouge and Aerodynamics Crimson yet again.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Well, ASTROLOGIC contains CORAL which is a synonym for red.

Comment: Coral is more orange to me than red. @RadoslavHristov. I included only certain red colors,  but if you prefer I would change it tonight.

Comment: @MariaDeleva Nah, just pointing it out.

Answer (score 2):

I think that

> Each word contains a '[superfood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superfood)'

For instance

> Diabetology contains 'date' which is considered a superfood
> Gastronomes contains 'oranges' which are also superfoods

@Will points out that

> Aeronautics contains Acai though it is an Unhealthy Word<sup>TM</sup>. Might be something to do with it being a [scam](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/judith-j-wurtman-phd/is-the-acai-berry-a-super_b_9636302.html)...?

Comment: AERONAUTICS has ACAI though

Comment: @Will, [thats considered a superfood](https://www.google.co.uk/search?rlz=1C1CHZL_enGB686GB686&q=is+acai+a+superfood&oq=is+acai+a+superfood&gs_l=serp.3..0j0i22i30k1l2.1250.1720.0.1985.4.4.0.0.0.0.104.288.3j1.4.0....0...1.1.64.serp..0.4.283.iS2_Lk-ORd0) I think

Comment: Yes, but it's an Unhealthy Word™.

Comment: Could be something to do with a lot of people think that that one is a [scam](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/judith-j-wurtman-phd/is-the-acai-berry-a-super_b_9636302.html)....

Comment: Or you could be barking under the wrong tree. :)